# How to identify dolphin lite browser from javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, css-position

I have a widget which unfortunately doesn't display well on Dolphin lite browsers since position:fixed is not supported.

The user agent string I see is :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; iw-il; X10i TripNMiUI
>   Build/NI1063) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile
>   Safari/533.1

How can I use this to identify dolphin browsers (any version) ?
Or is there another way to do that?

Alternatively I [found a code that checks for position=fixed support](http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED) but it looks risky to incorporate in production. Is there is a safe way to do this that could solve to my problem?

Comment: Why don't you want that code in production? Looks OK?

Comment: The user agent string for dolphin browser is `Mozilla/5.0 (SCH-F859/F859DG12;U;NUCLEUS/2.1;Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1;480*800;CTC/2.0) Dolfin/2.0`. try to find the string `"Dolphin"` in this string. I think that should get you through

Comment: Thanks! On dolphin Lite I get the one I sent. I will edit the question

Comment: @SunilKumarBM Feature detection should be preferred over parsing UA strings.

Comment: Rich Bradshaw- It looks like its changing the document size to 3000px and resize it back. to me it looks like a very processor intensive test just to check for position fixed. Potentially can cause delay and/or breakage of sites. Am I wrong?